# Changing the input value of the ng-select component while user types in angular 2

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-ngselect

I have an ng-select component. I want to trim the input text the user puts in as s/he types. I have the below code i can take the text the user types but i could not figure out a way to put the trimmed text back to ng-select.

```
<ng-select #vehicleInfoSelect [allowClear]="true"
   [(items)]="vehicleNumberList"
   (selected)="vehicleNoSelected($event)"
   (removed)="vehicleNoRemoved($event)"
   (typed)="vehicleNumberTyped($event)"
   placeholder="{{'vehicleInfo.placeHolder.filterVehicleNumberSelectBox'|translate}}">

</ng-select>
```

Typescript code

```
@ViewChild('vehicleInfoSelect') public vehicleInfoSelect: SelectComponent;

vehicleNumberTyped(text:String){
    console.log(text);
   // here i want to trim the text and
   // set the input field of the ng-select;
}
```

Any help would be great. Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

I guess this library does not provides this mechanism to do that. You can put some sort of hack for achieving this, by getting access to this private variable

```
this.behavior.filter(new RegExp(escapeRegexp(this.inputValue), 'ig'));
```

Which is available ng-select source code.

```
@ViewChild('vehicleInfoSelect') public vehicleInfoSelect: SelectComponent;

vehicleNumberTyped(text:String){
    console.log(text);
console.dir(this.vehicleInfoSelect);
}
```

If you can share the output of `console.dir(this.vehicleInfoSelect);` I can assist you further.

---

And the second way will be to `dispatchEvent` change event to input element of select, which will be more complex.

---

And the third way will be searching some other package which meets your requirement